# Are there limitations for playing video over wifi/3G on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, video, app-store

I have an app that is playing archived *.mov files from a server. Some of them are longer than 10 minutes. Is this ok? Can anyone point me to the guidelines for playing video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-SW5

> #### Requirements for Apps
>
> If your app delivers video over cellular networks, and the video exceeds either 10 minutes duration or 5 MB of data in a five minute period, you are required to use HTTP Live Streaming. (Progressive download may be used for smaller clips.)
>
> If your app uses HTTP Live Streaming over cellular networks, you are required to provide at least one stream at 64 Kbps or lower bandwidth (the low-bandwidth stream may be audio-only or audio with a still image).
>
> These requirements apply to iOS apps submitted for distribution in the App Store for use on Apple products. Non-compliant apps may be rejected or removed, at the discretion of Apple.